# How to I get my program to skip the uint32_t, then start reading the rest of the binary data into structs in C?

Tags: c, struct, binaryfiles

I have included my code below. I have it reading and printing the first line of a binary file. The rest of the file is meant to be put in a struct that contains a string, float and uint32_t. While it compiles and runs fine, I am getting very wrong values when printing each struct. I'm not sure what is wrong. I am not very familiar with C, so I have a hard time seeing the issue. I have an image of my output below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct Record
{
    char name[20];
    float gpa;
    uint32_t age;
} Record;


// Driver program
int main ()
{
    FILE *in;
    struct Record record;

    in = fopen("input.bin", "rb+");

    char *num = (char *)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
    fgets(num, 2, in);
    printf("%d\n", *num);

    if (in == NULL)
{
     return 3;
}

while(fread(&record, sizeof(struct Record), 1, in)){
    printf ("name = %s gpa = %f age: %d\n", record.name, record.gpa, record.age);
}

fclose (in);

return 0;
}
```

I also ended up trying another approach which also doesn't work.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


in = fopen("input.bin", "rb+");
char *num = (char *)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
fgets(num, 2, in);
printf("%d\n", *num);



while(!feof(in)) {
 
    Student st;

    char name[20];
    fread(&st.name, sizeof(char),1,in);
    
    float gpa;
    fread(&st.gpa, sizeof(float),1,in);
    
    uint32_t age;
    fread(&st.age, sizeof(uint32_t),1,in);
    
    
 
    printf("%d out of %d:\n", 1, *num);
    printf("Name: %s\n",st.name);
    printf("GPA: %.1f  (%s) \n",st.gpa, grade(gpa));
    printf("Age: %" PRIu32 "\n\n\n",st.age);
    
}
    
fclose(in);
```

This approach gets me an error. The solution is currently going over my head.

Comment: can you please provide a hex dump of the first 50 or so bytes of the file. on linux `od -tx1 <file name>`

Answer (score 0):

```
    char *num = (char *)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
    fgets(num, 2, in);
    printf("%d\n", *num);
```

fgets reads the `string` not the integer number

```
    unsigned num;
    fscanf(inm "%d", &num);
    printf("%d\n", *num);
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't seem to get this bit to work either. Am I able to switch a uint32_t with unsigned and it be the same?